# SQL select from data in query where this data is not already in the database?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to check my database for records that I already have recorded before making a web service call.

Here is what I imagine the query to look like, I just can't seem to figure out the syntax.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (1,2,3,4) as temp_table 
 WHERE temp_table.id 
LEFT JOIN table ON id IS NULL
```

Is there a way to do this? What is a query like this called?

I want to pass in a list of id's to mysql and i want it to spit out the id's that are not already in the database?

Comment: What's the `(1,2,3,4)`? You're trying to find out which of 1, 2, 3, 4 aren't already in table.id?

Comment: Exactly, I want to find out which of 1,2,3 and 4 isn't already a key in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm I've understood correctly, you want to pass in a list of numbers and see which of those numbers *isn't* present in the existing table? In effect:

```
SELECT Item
FROM IDList I
    LEFT JOIN TABLE T ON I.Item=T.ID
WHERE T.ID IS NULL
```

You look like you're OK with building this query on the fly, in which case you can do this with a numbers / tally table by changing the above into

```
SELECT Number
FROM (SELECT Number FROM Numbers WHERE Number IN (1,2,3,4)) I
    LEFT JOIN TABLE T ON I.Number=T.ID
WHERE T.ID IS NULL
```

This is relatively prone to SQL Injection attacks though because of the way the query is being built. It'd be better if you could pass in '1,2,3,4' as a string and split it into sections to generate your numbers list to join against in a safer way - for an example of how to do that, see http://www.sqlteam.com/article/parsing-csv-values-into-multiple-rows

All of this presumes you've got a numbers / tally table in your database, but they're sufficiently useful in general that I'd strongly recommend you do.

Comment: This is very interesting, it looks like this is specific to mssql right? all the same this is a fantastic answer!

Comment: Shouldn't be, can't see why it wouldn't work on MySQL or any other decent SQL database for that matter. You need to create a table containing literally just a sequential list of integers from 0 to whatever, but any database should support that and this is far from the only thing you can use one of them for.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
   SELECT x.id
     FROM (SELECT @param_1 AS id
             FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT @param_2
             FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT @param_3
             FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT @param_4
             FROM DUAL) x
LEFT JOIN TABLE t ON t.id = x.id
    WHERE x.id IS NULL
```

If you need to support a varying number of parameters, you can either use:

- [a temporary table](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm) to populate & join to
- [MySQL's Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) to dynamically construct the UNION ALL statement

Comment: Yeah this is a pretty hairy solution, if only this was python :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table where id NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: This isn't what I am looking for, I want to pass in a list of id's and I want to find out which ones aren't already recorded in mysql? I amended the question, it is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just do:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

And then process the list of results, removing any returned by the query from your list of "records to submit".

Comment: yeah, it just seemed like an interesting question to solve this entirely in the query

Comment: It is actually fairly interesting, trying to figure out a way to do it (without the giant UNION from OMG Ponies' answer), no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

How about a nested query? This may work. If not, it may get you in the right direction.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT id FROM table WHERE 1
);
```