# Creating a multi-row "table" as part of a SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm not really sure how to describe my question (thus the awful title), but it's related to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580812/sql-select-from-data-in-query-where-this-data-is-not-already-in-the-database).

The problem would be easily solved if there was some way for me to create a "table" with 4 rows as part of my SELECT (to use with NOT IN or MINUS).

What I mean is, I can do this:

```
SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

And will receive one row from the database:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

But is there any way to receive the following (without using UNION, I don't really want a query that's potentially thousands of lines long with a long list)?

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of query is possible in databases that support recursive queries (postgres, oracle, db2, mssql to name a few).

In mysql your (conceptually) easiest path would be to do create temporary table and then insert the IDs you are interested in as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580812/sql-select-from-data-in-query-where-this-data-is-not-already-in-the-database/2580874#2580874)

If you want it nicer, you could put the create temp table in mysql [stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to split a delimited constant input into a table is using a numbers / tally table - see http://www.sqlteam.com/article/parsing-csv-values-into-multiple-rows for more info. I've used this technique before on large datasets and found it pretty fast.